# MouseOutEvent from Sencha GXT Grid?

Tags: gwt, mouseevent, gxt

Need to catch `MouseOutEvent` when mouse leaves grid. Tried this:

```
grid.addHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}, MouseOutEvent.getType());
```

but it fires on every cell in grid. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution came from jQuery via JSNI:

```
private native void addMouseLeaveHandler(Element element) /*-{
        $wnd.$(element).mouseleave(function(){
             ....
        });
    }-*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, use `addDomHandler` instead.

```
grid.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}, MouseOutEvent.getType());
```

The difference is that addHandler does not wire the event up to the dom, but `addDomHandler` does. This *seems* to not always be required since once the event is wired up, it need not be done again, but as a good practice, every time you add a dom event handler to a widget, you should *always* use `addDomHandler` (or directly call `sinkEvents`, etc).

---

Okay, the real question asked was that too many events are going off, instead of just the general 'did the mouse leave the grid' event.

To handle this, check if the `eventTarget` of the event is the grid's own element. You are getting many events since you are getting all `mouseout` events for every element that is inside the grid, but just need to filter this down to the specific ones you are interested in.

This will look something like this:

```
grid.addDomHandler(new MouseOutHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onMouseOut(MouseOutEvent event) {
        //check event target of the event
        Element target = (Element) event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget();
        if (grid.getElement().equals(target) {
            // the mouse has left the entire grid
            // ...
        }
    }
}, MouseOutEvent.getType());
```

Comment: Might need to add more info on your question then - is there something custom in your grid or how it is being set up, etc. This works in my tests unless something is stopping it from working (stopPropagation() called on mouse events inside the grid, etc).

Comment: Of course I have custom Grid and etc.  But still - tried it with default Sencha Grid and GridView - same effect.  GWT 2.7.0, Sencha GXT 3.1.1

Comment: And structure was kinda like this:
`<VerticalPanel>
        <ContentPanel>
            <VerticalLayoutContainer>
                <container:child>
                      <Grid/>
                </container:child>
            </VerticalLayoutContainer>
        </ContentPanel>
    </VerticalPanel>`

Comment: No, last update in your answer didn't helped too - `event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget().cast()`  always gives cell, columnHeader and everything else as a `target` except grid's element. So it doesn't fires at all.

Comment: Probably there is a point to sink `Event.ONMOUSEOUT` for grid.getElement() but without its children, only `<div class="com-sencha-gxt-blablba-grid"></div>`. Or it is wrong idea?